# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' while doing PCA for k-means clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, spyder

I am trying to apply Kernel Principle Component Analysis on a dataset without a dependent variable to do a cluster analysis with k-means, so that I can learn how to do so. Here is a sample of my dataset(according to the scenario, this is a dataset of a shopping mall, and the shopping mall wants to discover the segments of its customers according to the data below):

```
CustomerID  Genre   Age Annual Income (k$)  Spending Score (1-100)
    1   Male    19  15  39
    2   Male    21  15  81
    3   Female  20  16  6
    4   Female  23  16  77
    5   Female  31  17  40
    6   Female  22  17  76
    7   Female  35  18  6
    8   Female  23  18  94
    9   Male    64  19  3
    10  Female  30  19  72
    11  Male    67  19  14
```

First, I omitted CustomerID column and then encoded the gender column to be able to apply kernel PCA. Here is how I did it:

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the mall dataset with pandas
dataset = pd.read_csv('Mall_Customers.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:5].values
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
#df is in order to visualize the "X" on variable explorer

#Encoding independent categorical variables 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

After executing this code, I could get the array with float64 Type. The sample from the array I created is below:

```
0   1   19  15  39
0   1   21  15  81
1   0   20  16  6
1   0   23  16  77
1   0   31  17  40
1   0   22  17  76
1   0   35  18  6
1   0   23  18  94
0   1   64  19  3
1   0   30  19  72
0   1   67  19  14
```

And then, I wanted to apply Kernel PCA to get the principal components which I will use at k-means. However, when I try to execute the code below, I get the error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'".

```
# Applying Kernel PCA 
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA
kpca = KernelPCA(n_components = 'None', kernel = 'rbf')
X = kpca.fit_transform(X)
explained_variance = kpca.explained_variance_ratio_
```

Even if I encoded my categorical data and I don't have any strings in my dataset, I cannot understand why it gives this error. Is there anyone that could help?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you create a simple reproduction of the issue?

Comment: Just a guess but you might have Nans or blanks in your array (X?). Are you sure that array you show is float64? Try something like `X.astype('float64')` and see if it gives you a problem.

Comment: @Stev No sir, I tried and it smoothly outputs the dataset smoothly, and there is no blank in my array either. Here the output I have after executing 
    X.astype('float64')

    array([[   0.,    1.,   19.,   15.,   39.],
       [   0.,    1.,   21.,   15.,   81.],
       [   1.,    0.,   20.,   16.,    6.],
       [   1.,    0.,   23.,   16.,   77.],
       [   1.,    0.,   31.,   17.,   40.],
       [   1.,    0.,   22.,   17.,   76.],
       [   1.,    0.,   35.,   18.,    6.],
       [   1.,    0.,   23.,   18.,   94.],.... etc.

Comment: @TomMakin simply the problem is that even if I have no string or categorical value in my dataset (because I encoded them), I cannot successfully execute kernel PCA and somehow I got this TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

Comment: @Beg, what do you think `n_components='auto'` is supposed to be doing? Try removing it?

Comment: @Beg, oops, that should say `n_components='None'`. If you want to set it to None (not needed because it is the default) then use `kpca = KernelPCA(n_components=None, kernel='rbf')`

Comment: As @Stev said, its just a typographical error. `None` is a Nonetype (null value) in python and `'None'` (surrounded with quotes) is a string. Correct that.

Comment: @TomMakin yes I changed it and worked without any problem, thank you, but this time when I fit it to X, it created a (200,200) array. I was aiming to see the explained variance ratios to choose the first n components, but there is no such attribute for kernel PCA, unlike normal PCA. Is there any way to check the explained variance ratios to decide how many Principle Components to use?

Answer (score 4):

`n_components = 'None'` is the problem. you should not put a string here...

use:
`kpca = KernelPCA(n_components = None, kernel = 'rbf')`

Answer (score -1):

I suspect this is what is happening:

This is an error of an included file, or some code that is running, prior to your running code. The "TypeError: '<' to which this is referring is a string "`<error>`". Which is what something prior to your code is returning.

Comment: If it is, is there a way that can I detect and eliminate it?